# Java Design/Spring Boot question, how to break down responsibilities inside a Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, chain-of-responsibility

Lets say you have a business flow that evolves around creating multiple queries on a songs database, and you have some steps in all

The example is in Spring Boot but the logic can be applied anywhere

1. Have a factory that decides the query
2. Parse: Receive some data, break them down, create the query
3. Query: Perform query on repository, the query returns a `List<SongItem>`
4. PrepareAnswer: Create a return DTO

Steps 2, 4, have different implementations, thus the different classes

you can create an interface or abstract class Query

```
private interface Query(){
    public ?? parse();
    public QueryBuilder createQuery();
    public ?? PrepareAnser();
}
```

and implement multiple `Query` types like `RockQuery` `PopQuery` `FolkQuery`

`public class RockQuery implements Query`

**How should the service be organized and the data `List<SongItem>` carried around the several steps?**

I have several thoughs, its mostly wether to include the SongList in the class or keep it in the Service

1)

```
@Service
public class SongService()

public SongListDTO makeAList(Data data){
    
    @Autowired
    SongRepository repository;
    
    Query query = factory(data).getQuery(Type.ROCK); // or something similar
    List<SongItem> songs = repository.query(query.createQuery());
    return query.prepareAnswer(songs);
    
}
```

2. 

instead of creating a different querytype, actually perform the query inside the QueryClass, not the Service. Of course inject the repository there.

Keep the `List<SongItem>` as class member. Dont expose it to the `Service`

```
public SongListDTO makeAList(Data data){
    Query query = factory(data).getQuery(Type.ROCK); // or something similar
    query.performQuery()
    return query.prepareAnswer(songs);
}
```

3. Something similar, multiple variations may apply

Answer (score 1):

I did not follow the code snippet you provided, but you can follow the following approach:

```
@Service
public class SongService {
  
  private final SongRepository songRepository;
  private final QueryFactory queryFactory;
  private final PrepareAnswerFactory prepareAnswerFactory;

  @Autowired
  public SongService(SongRepository songRepository, QueryFactory queryFactory, PrepareAnswerFactory prepareAnswerFactory) {
    this.songRepository = songRepository;
    this.queryFactory = queryFactory;
    this.prepareAnswerFactory = prepareAnswerFactory;
  }

  public List<SongDTO> getSongsByQueryType(String queryType) {
    // Create query instance using factory method
    Query query = queryFactory.createQuery(queryType);

    // Parse the data, create the query, and execute it on the repository
    List<SongItem> songs = songRepository.findByQuery(query.parse(), query.createQueryBuilder());

    // Create return DTO
    PrepareAnswer prepareAnswer = prepareAnswerFactory.createPrepareAnswer(queryType);
    List<SongDTO> songDTOs = prepareAnswer.prepareAnswer(songs);

    return songDTOs;
  }
}
```

In this example, the `SongService` class is the service class that coordinates the different steps. The `SongRepository` is a Spring Data JPA repository interface that handles the database interactions.

The `QueryFactory` and `PrepareAnswerFactory` are factory classes that provide instances of the corresponding Query and `PrepareAnswer` implementations based on the `queryType` parameter.

The `getSongsByQueryType` method takes in the `queryType` parameter, which determines the type of query required. It then creates an instance of the corresponding `Query` implementation using the `QueryFactory`, parses the data, creates the query, and executes it on the repository.

The `List<SongItem>` result is then passed to the corresponding `PrepareAnswer` implementation, created using the `PrepareAnswerFactory`, to create the return DTO.